# `$` variable in .env not the same after loading through symfony-dotenv

Tags: php, symfony, dotenv

Putting `$` symbols in an environment variable in a `.env` file,
the [symfony/dotenv](https://github.com/symfony/dotenv) loader seems to mess something up.

`.env`

```
TEST=123123123!!!123123123$$LOST$$testtesttest~~~tiltiltiltil
```

`test.php`

```
<?php
require_once __DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php';

$dotenv = new \Symfony\Component\Dotenv\Dotenv();
$dotenv->load('.env');

print_r($_ENV);
```

Output:

```
[TEST] => 123123123!!!123123123$$~~~tiltiltiltil
```

Expected output:

```
[TEST] => 123123123!!!123123123$$LOST$$testtesttest~~~tiltiltiltil
```

My question is if this is a bug or me doing something wrong.

It does not matter whether I wrap the value in quotes.

If it's not me, I'd create an issue on GitHub.

Comment: Is it assuming that they are variable substitutions?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `$` sign has a special meaning so to insert a literal dollar you need to either quote it or escape it:

```
TEST='123123123!!!123123123$$LOST$$testtesttest~~~tiltiltiltil'
TEST=123123123!!!123123123\$\$LOST\$\$testtesttest~~~tiltiltiltil
```